# Used mybatisPlus. Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I used Springboot+[MybatisPlus](https://baomidou.com/en/) in the project When I did not add MybatisPlus, I could successfully build a native image and run it successfully.
Join MybatisPlus, although it can be compiled and generated native image, but the running error. Error memory is as follows:

```sh
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-12 08:23:32.757 ERROR 4751 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.fandow.oa.OaStaffApplication#MapperScannerRegistrar#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1318) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:751) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at com.fandow.oa.OaStaffApplication.main(OaStaffApplication.java:22) ~[com.fandow.oa.oastaffapplication:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1310) ~[na:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:3349) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(DynamicHub.java:2553) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) ~[na:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fandow</groupId>
    <artifactId>oa-staff</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oa-staff</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-boot.version>2.4.0</spring-boot.version>
        <oa-common.version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</oa-common.version>
        <tomcat-embed-programmatic-version>9.0.38.1-dev</tomcat-embed-programmatic-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-programmatic</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat-embed-programmatic-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graalvm-native</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fandow.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>oa-common-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fandow.framework</groupId>
                <artifactId>oa-common-web</artifactId>
                <version>${oa-common.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>20.3.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.fandow.oa.OaStaffApplication</mainClass>
                            <buildArgs>
                                -Dspring.graal.skip-logback=true
                                -Dspring.graal.verbose=true
                                -Dspring.native.remove-yaml-support=true
                                -Dspring.spel.ignore=true
                                --trace-class-initialization=org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
                                --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime
                                --enable-https
                                -H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime
                                -H:+AddAllCharsets
                                --allow-incomplete-classpath
                                --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces
                                --no-server
                                -H:IncludeResourceBundles=javax.servlet.http.LocalStrings
                                -H:IncludeResourceBundles=javax.servlet.LocalStrings
                                --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.unix.Socket
                                --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.unix.IovArray
                                --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop
                                --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.unix.Errors
                                --initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
                            </buildArgs>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>native-image</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.fandow.oa.OaStaffApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

### Bootstrap Application

```java
package com.fandow.oa;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 2020-12-12
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods=false)
@MapperScan("com.fandow.oa.infrastructure.mapper")
public class OaStaffApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OaStaffApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### Error screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It should be a version problem, try to upgrade the mybatisplus version

Comment: I don't think it was the version because I used the latest version of MyBatisPlus.